# Show icon depending on not empty value

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

[image]

I want to show this drop-right icon if there is any submenu under it. Asia has countries on submenu(countries under it(china/korea) but USA doesn't have.

Drop down menu formation

[image]

Html

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-custom btn btn-outline-light text-light" 
  style="font-family: Times New Roman; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;">Country</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      @foreach($subcontinents as $subcontinent)
      <a><div class="dropdown2">
      @if(is_null($subcontinent->countries))
      <button class="dropbtn2">{{$subcontinent->subcontinent_name}}</button>
      @else
      <button class="dropbtn2">{{$subcontinent->subcontinent_name}}<i class="fa fa-caret-right pl-3" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
      @endif
                      
     <div class="dropdown-content2">
      @foreach($subcontinent->countries as $division)
         <a href="" >{{$division->country_name}}</a>
      @endforeach
                       
    </div>
   </div>
  </a>
 @endforeach
 </div>
</div>
```

**Database**

*Subcontinent has many countries.*

If one subcontinent has countries/not empty countries then there will be drop-right icon.

Comment: If you have a true one-to-many eloquent relationship then  `$subcontinent->countries` will not be null it will be an empty collection so it's safer to do `optional($subcontinent->countries)->isEmpty())` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-custom btn btn-outline-light text-light" 
      style="font-family: Times New Roman; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;">Country</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          @foreach($subcontinents as $subcontinent)
          <a><div class="dropdown2">
            <button class="dropbtn2">{{$subcontinent->subcontinent_name}} 
              // You can check here if your values aren't empty or greater than 0. based on that you can show. you can also use !empty() here.
              @if(count($subcontinent->countries) > 0)<i class="fa fa-caret-right pl-3" aria-hidden="true"></i>@endif 
            </button>
          <div class="dropdown-content2">
           @foreach($subcontinent->countries as $division)
              <a href="" >{{$division->country_name}}</a>
           @endforeach   
        </div>
       </div>
      </a>
     @endforeach
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation on what wasn't working/what you fixed instead of just dumping code.

Comment: okay. commented.

Comment: Okay sorry about that. But it's working with the solution now.